# Why is gridview.selectedColumns nothing?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to run a code like this, but it always jumps over the loop, so I see no line in the console. 
That means that selectedColumns is empty. My assumption was that I (or the user) select a cell from a Column and then, selectedColummns are +1. But as it looks, it doesnt work.  Then I tried to set proberties of selectionMode to select full columns, but then  an exception is thrown:

> "System.InvalidOperationException" Additional Information: the SortMode cannot be Automatic, if full Column selection is selected.

I don't know what SortMode is.

```
 For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In datagridview2.SelectedColumns

        Console.Write(datagridview2.SelectedColumns.Count)
        Console.Write("1")


    Next
```

Any Ideas how to get that the columns into selectedColumns?

Here my code that solved my problem, but I guess it is not the smartest one:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim body As String = ""

    Dim myWriter As New StreamWriter("H:\downloads\test.csv", True)
    Dim list As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)

    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In datagridview2.SelectedCells

        If list.Contains(cell.ColumnIndex) = False Then
            list.Add(cell.ColumnIndex)
        End If

    Next


    For i = 0 To datagridview2.Rows.Count - 1

        For ix = 0 To datagridview2.Columns.Count - 1

            If list.Contains(ix) Then

                If datagridview2.Rows(i).Cells(ix).Value IsNot Nothing Then

                    body = body + datagridview2.Rows(i).Cells(ix).Value.ToString + ";"
                Else
                    body = body + ";"
                End If

            End If

        Next
        myWriter.WriteLine(body)
        body = ""

    Next

    myWriter.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this after the selected changed event has fired. 
For example:

```
Private Sub Mydg_ColSelected(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.SelectionChanged

   For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In datagridview2.SelectedColumns

    Console.Write(datagridview2.SelectedColumns.Count)
    Console.Write("1")

    Next

End Sub
```

Or if this isn't what you are after, then try handling the ColumnHeaderMouseClick event instead. I'm not sure what technology you are using, e.g Winforms, WPF, silverlight

Comment: ColumnHeaderMouseClick or ColSelected change event will not work, because I need to write the selected columns into a .csv file. Nevertheless, now I managed it through selectedcell.columnindex Look my Edit in 1 minute :)